# Jquery AJAX - JSON property being shortened

Tags: json, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I am working on a project in MVC2, I have a controller action to respond to a jQuery AJAX call which returns a JSON respose. One of the properties in my JSON is extremely long (can be 500k characters), and seems to be clipped to a max length of 43676 characters after reaching my Jquery AJAX success function.

I have done a lot of debugging, and as far as I can tell, the controller is passing the JSON correctly to the client. I can capture the network response in IE dev tools and see that the JSON is still valid. But once it reaches my JavaScript one of the properties is shortened.

Below is some example code to try and explain a bit better.

```
/// MVC2 Controller action
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    /// Generate a simple object with a few properties
    object response = GetResponse();       

    //make the return string max length huge
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer { MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue };
    ContentResult result = new ContentResult
    {
        ContentType = "application/json",
        Content = serializer.Serialize(response)
    };
    return result;
}

/// Example of the response object
class response
{
    public string Property1;
    public string Property2;
    public string Property3;
}

/// jQuery AJAX call
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/MyAction",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(results) {
        //Accessing a JSOn property that comes after the long one still works fine
        if(results.Property3 === 'Success') {
            //Do something with one of the JSON properties
            $('#MyDiv1').val(results.Property1);

            //I get a JS error here because my HTML is invalid due to the string being clipped
            $('#MyDiv2').html(results.Property2);
        }
    }
});
```

I have simplified my code a lot to try and make this clear. I have a very long html string in Property2, but it is being shortened to 43676 characters. I am really not sure what is happening at this point. The thing that confuses me is that the controller action seems to pass the correct JSON to the client, and more confusingly, the long JSON property (Property2) is in the middle of my JSON somewhere, and this is the only value that gets affected. If the JSON was just too long, wouldn't the properties after my long value also be missing? Does jQuery AJAX or JSON in general have a max length on properties?

Comment: can you try initializing of the serializer object without length ?

Comment: just tried and it has the same result. When I capture the network response in IE dev tools, the respnse body is complete, but debugging the javascript, the results.Property2 has been shortened. Or at least it looks that way, IE dev tools doesn't have a max string length when inspecting JavaScript properties does it? But the JavaScript error I get 'Unterminated string constant' seems to back up the fact that the string has been clipped.